# Turning a Page Object Into Its Page Derived Object

Tags: django, wagtail

I am new to wagtail but I keep running into something that I am sure there is a better solution for than what I am currently doing.

Lets say I have a Wagtail Page called ProductPage. Lets say this page has a field that is another ProductPage called related_product. When I try to access this page in my templates or context by the following code,

```
self.related_product
```

it returns a Page object instead of a ProductPage object. Because of this, I cannot get to the fields that I actually want to without transforming it into a ProductPage object by way of,

```
ProductPage.objects.get(page_ptr_id=self.related_product.id)
```

There has to be a way to transform this without this above query.

Comment: How to link pages properly in Wagtail is shown here - https://godjango.com/search/?q=wagtail. The tutorials are not free, but pretty cheap, and registration can be cancelled at any time. Saying that, I have used his tutorials for over a year now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to go from a `Page` instance to the more specific model is to access the `specific` property:

```
product_page = some_page.specific  # returns a ProductPage instance
```

However, this will internally perform a database query, so it isn't any more efficient than your code above (just more readable). If you have a queryset of `Page`s, you can improve things slightly by calling `specific()` on the queryset, which will perform one extra query for each different page type that exists in the queryset:

```
product_pages = product_index.get_children().specific()
```

In your case, though, there's a much better solution: if the `related_product` field will only ever be used to link to a `ProductPage` and not any other kind of page, then you should indicate this in the data model by having your foreign key point to `ProductPage`, rather than `Page`:

```
class ProductPage(Page):
    # ...
    related_product = models.ForeignKey('myapp.ProductPage', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

When you do this, accessing `some_page.related_product` will always give you the `ProductPage` instance. As an added benefit, the page chooser popup in the Wagtail admin will ensure that you can only pick ProductPages (and if all your ProductPages are in the same place in your page tree, will take you directly there).